# Reactjs : display time in 24hr format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to print time in 24hour format using react js. And I have used the below example,which gives 12 hour format. Any ideas to get 24 hr format?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-time-picker

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried setting the `locale` prop to a language that uses 24 hour format?

Comment: Nope..iam new to react. how can I use that?I have this <TimePicker onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.time} />

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `locale` prop that uses the 24 hour format instead of the am/pm format.

E.g. Sweden `sv-sv` uses the 24 hour format.

**Example ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/o46z1m8wrz))**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    time: "10:00"
  };

  onChange = time => this.setState({ time });

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: "200px" }}>
        <TimePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.time}
          locale="sv-sv"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```